# Automating a Fluid Dispenser with an Arduino

Tags: arduino, actuator

I would like to automate a process which will require applying force to the plunger of a 5ml syringe to dispense fluid at about 10ul per second onto a 25 mm by 75mm surface and I am thinking of using an arduino to control an actuator that will apply this force to the plunger. I am not sure if this is the best way to go or the best way to go about it . Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: What's the nature of the actuator?

Comment: I was planning to use a linear actuator that  applies low force more or less like this http://store.firgelli.com/Firgelli_L12_S_p/l12-s.htm?1=1&CartID=1

Answer (score 1):

The fluid dispenser I use has a pneumatically actuated syringe that uses a regulator and a flow control valve to control the rate of dispensing. There is a solenoid valve controlled by a timer and foot switch that determines the total amount dispensed. You could replace the timer with your Ard**o.

Answer (score 0):

One suggested answer is pnuematics. However, if you do not have the space or money for a pnuematic set up you can also you a linear actuator, or linear servo.  This would give more precise control for less money.  The downside is that it would be much slower than pnuematics.

Answer (score 0):

The way this is typically done is with a syringe pump - a stepper and lead-screw driving a syringe. They are very precise both in dispense volume and rate of delivery.